# Contacts - how to distinguish between SIM, phone and other contacts?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I'm reading ALL contacts from the phone like following:

```
Cursor cursor = MainApp.get().getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");
```

I read `ContactsContract.Data.ACCOUNT_TYPE_AND_DATA_SET` and `ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME` from the contacts and analysed them because I want to distinguish between phone, sim and any other contact... But I only can see that the values are very phone specific.

**1) I currently only know following values for `ContactsContract.Data.ACCOUNT_TYPE_AND_DATA_SET`:**

- Phone contacts

  - `com.sonyericsson.localcontacts (Sony Xperia S)`
  - `vnd.sec.contact.phone (Samsung Galaxy Alpha)`
- SIM contacts

  - `com.sonyericsson.adncontacts (Sony Xperia S)`
  - `vnd.sec.contact.sim (Samsung Galaxy Alpha)`

**2) I currently only know following values for `ContactsContract.Data.ACCOUNT_NAME`:**

- Phone contacts

  - `Phone contacts` (Sony Xperia S)
  - EMPTY (Samsung Galaxy Alpha)
- SIM contacts

  - `SIM contacts` (Sony Xperia S)
  - `primary.sim.account_name` (Samsung Galaxy Alpha)

Google, WhatsApp, Viber contacts are easy to recognise, but how to find out it a contact is a phone contact or a sim contact on all phones (or at least on most)?

I don't want to display "vnd.sec.contact.sim" for sim contacts but  want to display "SIM" instead.

Does anyone know other strings for my list?
Or does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

To get contacts from SIM use this:

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
    Cursor cursorSim    = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null,null, null);

     while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {           
         listName.          add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name")));
         listContactId.     add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("_id")));      
         listMobileNo.      add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number")));
        }
```

name, _id, number are fields in SIM contacts table

And for the contacts from phone use

```
   Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(
   RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
   new String[]{RawContacts._ID,RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE},
   RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'com.anddroid.contacts.sim' "
    + " AND " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'com.google' " //if you don't want to google contacts also
   ,
   null,
   null);
```

Comment: For the second part: SIM contacts not always seem to be named `com.anddroid.contacts.sim`. And I would have to exclude all other accounts like google as well, like whatsapp, viber and so on (would be possible but I don't know all apps that create contacts and every developer can save their contacts in the phone)

Comment: Is it possible to get how SIM and local contacts should have in their  ACCOUNT_TYPE field?